# Importing Excel to DataGrid then save to MySQL database

Tags: c#, database, excel, forms

When I import the Excel file into dataGridView1 and click 'Update' all the data isn't storing into my database:

[Database pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8DO2.png)
[image: Database pic]

[My rota form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3yoo.png)
[image: My rota form]

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Login
{
    public partial class EmployeeRota : Form
    {
        public SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=dqq5ndqef2.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=Login;Integrated Security=False;User ID=richardjacobs97;Password=;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
        public SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        public DataTable table = new DataTable();

        public EmployeeRota()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string PathCpnn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " + textBox1.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(PathCpnn);

            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + textBox2.Text + "$]", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            myDataAdapter.Update(dt);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Id, Name, Date FROM Rota", this.connection);

            SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Rota (Id, Name, Date) VALUES (@id, @name, @date)", this.connection);
            SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Rota SET Id = @id, Name = @name, Date = @date", this.connection);

            insert.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45, "Id");
            insert.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45, "Name");
            insert.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45, "Date");

            update.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45, "Id");
            update.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45, "Name");
            update.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar, 45, "Date");

            this.adapter.InsertCommand = insert;
            this.adapter.UpdateCommand = update;

            this.adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
        }

        private void EmployeeRota_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Why won't it store in my database?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be, unless you have a specific requirement that the data has to be viewable on a form, to do away with that entirely and look at ETL solutions (Extract, Transform, Load) between Excel and Mysql.

There are several of them out there, and Google is your friend...

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing this part

```
this.adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

this.adapter.UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```